# "bundle update" not working and installing in older version directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundle, bundler

In my jekyll folder, `jekyll serve` didn't work, showed missing dependencies.

On running `bundle update` in my jekyll site folder, it shows an error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20200629-9481-3yqsb7.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri- 
1.10.9/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.9' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds 
before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 6.0.3.2, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 6.0.3.2, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 6.0.3.2, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 6.0.3.2, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri
```

The issue is, it's trying to install gem in directory of older ruby version 2.5.0, which I have uninstalled. Currently, my ruby version is(installed using rmv):

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
```

The ruby in use also shows same:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby
```

The bundle directory in use:

```
$ which bundle
/home/devesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/bundle
```

So how can I fix this issue, so that on bundle update, it generates gems in new gem directory?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try `gem install bundler` first, then do `bundle update`

Comment: bundler is already installed, yet I tried this and it didn't work